# GetFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.graph_fragment_holder, new GraphFragment(), "GRAPH_FRAGMENT")
                .commit();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.list_fragment_holder, new ListFragment(), "LIST_FRAGMENT")
                .commit();

        //getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        GraphFragment graphFragment = (GraphFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("GRAPH_FRAGMENT");
        graphFragment.setData(data);

        ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LIST_FRAGMENT");
        listFragment.setData(data);
```

I've supplied a tag so I'm not sure why `findFragmentByTag()` returns `null`.

**What I've tried from reading other questions:**

1. `this.setRetainInstance(true)` in the `oncreate` of both `fragments`.
2. Both `fragment` constructors are empty `public fragmentName(){}`.
3. tried `executePendingTransactions` after adding the `fragments`.
4. tried `add` instead of `replace` on the `fragments` (edited)

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I have related question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same problem of `findFragmentByTag()` always returning null.

Eventually I tracked it down, I was overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` in my Activity but not calling super. As soon as I fixed that `findFragmentByTag()` returned the Fragment as expected.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. And doesn't work mixed with @Dmitry Dudá answer. I have not used `addToBackStack`.

Comment: did not help. I am not overriding it.

Answer (score 28):

I was confused about this for a long time. First, you need to save the fragment you are replacing by pushing it onto the back stack. The tag you supply is put on the fragment you are *adding*, not the one you are *pushing* onto the back stack. Later, when you do push it onto the back stack, that tag goes with it. Here's code with objects broken out to make it easier to trace. You must call 'addToBackStack' before 'commit'.

```
GraphFragment grFrag = new GraphFragment();
FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, grFrag, "GRAPH_FRAGMENT");
// grFrag is about to become the current fragment, with the tag "GRAPH_FRAGMENT"
tr.addToBackStack(null);
// 'addToBackStack' also takes a string, which can be null, but this is not the tag
tr.commit();
// any previous fragment has now been pushed to the back stack, with it's tag

ListFragment liFrag = new ListFragment();
FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, liFrag, "LIST_FRAGMENT");
// liFrag is is about to become the current fragment, with the tag "LIST_FRAGMENT"
tr.addToBackStack(null);
tr.commit();
// 'grFrag' has now been pushed to the back stack, with it's tag being "GRAPH_FRAGMENT"
```

Comment: Thank you. The distinction between the string tag that is supplied in the replace, and the backstack tag are two different things. That was tripping me up for a while

Comment: This is the right answer as the TAG needs to be added in replace/add methods and not the addToBackStack(TAG) method as it has nothing to do with findFragmentByTag(TAG).

Comment: Nice explanation. Saved me buddy

Comment: @Chapz Not for me. I needed addToBackStack.

Comment: tr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, liFrag, "LIST_FRAGMENT"); This worked for me .i have not added 3rd parameter  first and also add tag to addToBackStack("LIST_FRAGMENT")

Answer (score 19):

Call getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions() after fragment transaction.

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new ExampleFragment(), "YOUR TAG HERE");
    .commit();

//after transaction you must call the executePendingTransaction
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

//now you can get fragment which is added with tag
ExampleFragment exampleFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR TAG HERE");
```

Comment: You should add some explanation / background information to your answer to make it more valuable. (and put `getSupport...` in backticks ``)

Comment: It doesn't help me with androidX

Comment: This works, but A better explanation would be appreciated, One day it was working without this and the following day it was needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(yourFragmentTag);
```

After that you can reuse it with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(yourFragmentTag);
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` don't solve problem **because**
he may don't extends from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in two fragments

Comment: and he may don't need to add his fragments to back stack too

Comment: @ahmedhamdy sure. it was a quick answer. if he does not use support library he can use getFragmentManager(); and he can add all fragments which want to reuse and find them and reuse later.

Comment: addtoBackStack was what I was missing :-P

Comment: I also had the same problem, I used addToBackStack(TAG), but the problem was in add(container, fragment). I've changed it to add(container, fragment, TAG) and the problem gone away

Answer (score 2):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170693/4810625), just need to call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` after your findByTag or findById

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to create a class level FragmentManager object and then use it instead of using getSupportFragmentManager() directly.

```
public class Main extends BaseActivity {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragmain);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    initFrag1();
  }

  private void initFrag1() {
    String name = Frag1.class.getSimpleName();
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name) == null) {
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
          .add(R.id.frag_container, new Frag1(), name)
          .addToBackStack(name)
          .commit();
    }
  }
}
```