# Removing a fragment using its tag is not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to add , then remove a fragment using its tag .

in my **MainActivity.java** file I have the following code :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragment1 myFragment = new fragment1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container , myFragment , "mytag").commit() ;
       Fragment myFragment2 =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mytag");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(myFragment2).commit();


    }
}
```

and the **fragment1.java** file has the following code only :

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
    }


}
```

However , when I run this application it crashes as soon as it launch and the reason is

> Attempting to write on a null object

which means that findFragmentByTag function is returning a **null** object .

My logcat :

> 08-19 12:59:46.605 31377-31377/com.example.first.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.first.myapplication, PID: 31377
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.first.myapplication/com.example.first.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field
>   'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:770)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:604)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6288)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

Comment: provide your logcat with exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581894/getfragmentmanager-findfragmentbytag-returns-null?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: try commitNow instead of commit. transaction.commit is async call and just schedules it. commitNow is supposed to be synchronous

Answer (score 0):

No better options is replace fragment?

Something like this:

```
public void showSpinner(boolean show) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (show) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.browse_frame_layout, new SpinnerFragment(),
                getString(R.string.spinner_fragment))
                .commit();
    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.spinner_fragment)))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to delete the fragment , and not replace it .

Comment: try make if(when fragmenta.isAdded){
fragmentb.remove();
}

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: see editet answer, u need to handle is like this one on top

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentManagerMenu.beginTransaction().add(R.id.superContainer, PersonalUsersListFragment.newInstance(userList, usersId), "PersonalUsersListFragment").addToBackStack("menuStack").commit();
```

and clear         `fragmentManagerMenu.popBackStack("menuStack", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container , myFragment , "mytag").commitNow() ;
```

Instead of :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container , myFragment , "mytag").commit() ;
```

Solved the problem because commit() is async function and commitNow is synchronous.

Thank you .