# Reuse same Fragment instance

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make Android app less memory expensive
And wonder is there a way to reuse one instance of a Fragment without recreating it?
In my app I have a few fragments (which are memory expensive)
and user usually navigates a lot of the times between them.

Using of back stack doesn't allow me to achieve desired.
For instance if I add transactions to back stack in this way:
FragA -> FragB -> FragC -> FragD
and when user returns to the FragA (which is a main menu in the app) by using `popBackStack("FragA.class.getSimpleName()", 0)`,
I lose FragB -> FragC -> FragD instances.
Then when user navigates in the same direction:
FragA -> FragB -> FragC -> FragD
last 3 fragments have to be created again.

I tried solutions advised here:
[Can fragment be created with only one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154341/can-fragment-be-created-with-only-one-instance)
[How to keep only one instance of a fragment, when switching with NavigationDrawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972103/how-to-keep-only-one-instance-of-a-fragment-when-switching-with-navigationdrawe)
But they neither help.

I end up with this solution but it still doesn't work:

```
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private HashMap<String, Fragment> mFragmentsMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentsMap = new HashMap<>();

// ...

}


public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {

//      getting Fragment name
        String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();

//      checking whether fragment has been created
        Fragment usedFragment = mFragmentsMap.get(fragmentName);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (usedFragment == null) {
//            don't have fragment created
//            creating new one and putting to the map
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentPanel, fragment, fragmentName);
            mFragmentsMap.put(fragmentName, fragment);

        } else {
         // having needed Fragment created
         // so reusing it
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentPanel, usedFragment, fragmentName);

        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

In this case interesting situation happened:
If from FragD I want to return to FragA with using of
    `switchFragment(FragA);`
HashMap already holds FragA instance and I am replacing 
container with usedFragment (from the method above),
but somehow FragA gets created again.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're only going to create problems for yourself or the next developer who gets to see your code. I doubt there will be any efficiency you'd achieve this way. Nonetheless, does your fragment perform heavy operations upon initialization?

Comment: Yes, some kind of heavy operations are performed in onCreate()

Comment: so Fragment has to be recreated all the times?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. Do you want to go back to FragA and close all fragments on top of it? For example, you opened FragA then opened FragB on top of it, then FragC. Now you want to close FragC and FragB, right?

Comment: Nope. I want to "keep somewhere" FragB and FragC in order not to create them again when after returning to FragA user will go again to FragB and FragC

Comment: You should be looking to caching instead. I guess you can store the cache in file, SQLite or `SharedPreference`.